# How can I include new assets with `ng serve`?

Tags: angular, jit, angular2-aot

Previous assets are included, but I added a new folder in my assets folder and it's not included when I run `ng serve`.

When I run `ng build` the new folder is included in the dist though.

It appears to be a known issue [(1)](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/9669) [(2)](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/6329), but the possible solutions I tried haven't worked:

When running `ng serve` I have included the `--aot` flag, trying out both `true` and `false`.

In `angular.json` in the project's build options I included assets as thus:

```
"assets": [
  {
    "glob": "**/*",
    "input": "src/assets",
    "output": "assets"
  }
],
```

and also like this:

```
"assets": [
  "src/assets",
],
```

And I updated my angular version in `package.json` from `^7.1.3` to `^7.2.15`

Comment: do you `serve` has the good `browserTarget` in your angular.json ?

Comment: @Gilsdav yes, it targets the default build which worked previously. Just with my new assets it doesn't work.

Comment: did you find solution @Friso